# Not able to load logo on the web

Tags: laravel

Hope you can clarify this issue:

I am trying to ad a favicon to my website in the head of my html layout, the link i am using is :

```
href="{{ asset('assets/public/images/favicon-32x32.png') }}"
```

I have my file in the following route:

backend/public/images/icon.png

the icon is not displaying on the web anyway, any idea about what can be the issue here?
thanks

Comment: where is the icon full path from project name down ?

Comment: In web inspector what is the result? 
Is it display {{ asset('assets/public/images/favicon-32x32.png') }} or nothing?

Comment: the public here "backend/public/images/icon.png" is it the laravel public folder?

Comment: when uploading and saving your file, try saving it in the front end public folder of the website

Comment: `asset('images/favicon-32x32.png')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as in laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-asset)

> The asset function generates a URL for an asset using the current
> scheme of the request (HTTP or HTTPS):
>
> ```
> $url = asset('img/photo.jpg');
> ```
>
> You can configure the asset URL host by setting the ASSET_URL variable
> in your .env file. This can be useful if you host your assets on an
> external service like Amazon S3:
> // ASSET_URL=http://example.com/assets
>
> ```
> $url = asset('img/photo.jpg'); // http://example.com/assets/img/photo.jpg
> ```

so if you use default ASSET_URL value in .env file and your favicon file in file structure like :

***project_Folder/public/images/favicon.ico***

so you need to make your link like

```
{{-- favicon --}}
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('images/favicon-32x32.png') }}">
```